# Rails Model Custom Validation Won't Work On Update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I try to create some model validation on my Coupon Model
evrything work on create, but when i try to update data the validation won't validate
the first validation is to raise error if percentage more than 100
the second validation is to  validate if date start bigger than date expired it will throw some error

my model in this code:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Coupon < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :transactions, dependent: :restrict_with_exception
  has_one :battery, through: :transactions
  enum :discount_type, %i[percentage nominal]
  validates :code, format: { with: /\A[0-9A-Z]+\Z/ },
                   presence: true,
                   uniqueness: true,
                   length: { maximum: 50 },
                   on: :create,
                   allow_nil: false
  validate :discount_value, :discount_type
  validate :discount_value_percentage

  validates :start_at, :expired_at, presence: true
  validate :end_date_after_start_date

  def discount_value_percentage
    return unless discount_type == 'percentage' && discount_value > 100

    errors.add(:discount_value, 'discount value percentage cannot over 100%')
  end

  def end_date_after_start_date
    return if expired_at.blank? || start_at.blank?

    return unless expired_at < start_at

    errors.add(:expired_at, 'must be after the start date')
  end
end
```

Please help me to resolve my problem

the validation can validate if date start bigger than date end it will throw error code

Comment: Please edit your question to include the error code and any messages from the console having to do with the issue.

Comment: How are you triggering the save? certain methods don't trigger validations

Comment: @Beartech therese no error message, in this case i want to show error message

Comment: @Edward i use update

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are either of your validations working? It sounds like one of your validations ISN'T working, but is that the case? When I say errors I am referring to the web console. Do you know where to look for that?

Comment: @MohammadAdityaNoviansyah Please add code snippet from where you are updating coupon model.